# Enabling ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension by default?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, arcgis-license-manager, error-010096

Anyone know a way to have the Spatial Analyst extension enabled by default?

We have ArcGIS with extensions installed on multiple windows systems in computer labs and when I logon as an admin on any the compluters and run ArcMap open a amp and try to run Spatial Analyst it gives me a license error "you do not have the necessary license to execute the selected tool ERROR 010096" 
The license is present, it seems that every use I need to go in and check the spatial analyst checkbox in extensions. The same applies for each user.

I'm hoping there might be a registry setting or some other setting that I can set that will check the spatial analyst checkbox by default for all users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Esri Support

http://communityhub.esriuk.com/technicalsupport/2014/3/23/silently-enable-extensions-for-arcgis-for-desktop-10x.html

It is possible to activate extensions silently during installation so that individual users do not have to do this manually.

The enable setting for each of the extensions is held in the registry at the following location:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.x\ArcMap\Extensions

or

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.x\ArcCatalog\Extensions

When ArcMap/ArcCatalog is first opened, none of the extensions are enabled, and the registry keys above are empty. As extensions are enabled within ArcMap/ArcCatalog, a new DWORD is created in the above locations, and assigned a value of 1 (Enabled) or 2 (Disabled).

It is therefore possible to pre-populate these keys with the following DWORD entries (set to value =1) to enable all of the extensions during installation:

```
3D Analyst: {94305472-592E-11D4-80EE-00C04FA0ADF8} 
ArcScan: {A212F759-F155-4BAF-A692-B9268CF9A465}
CrimeAnalyst: {E40B6CD1-E7D0-442A-BB4C-D481914401C9}
Data Interoperability: {D5E016E9-171B-45CA-B4A2-6361DBC1E255}
Geostatistical Analyst: {DE0502C4-8D34-11D3-A63A-0008C7BF3347}
Network Analyst: {C967BD39-1118-42EE-AAAB-B31642C89C3E}
Productivity Suite: {B633FD03-46C1-44E8-BC4A-185E02D1CD5E}
Publisher: {8AEE0DE1-535C-4788-95C8-1659444D4C02}
Schematics: {EE89C7C1-20BB-4412-8239-301179CA4F0D}
Spatial Analyst: {3C5059FE-9F15-401A-94ED-EED914D73E3E}
Tracking Analyst: {D53BF20F-24FB-11D4-B34C-00104BA2ABCC}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very prompt response. I searched esri via google but did not get this hit.  I'll try this out now and mark the question answered if it works for me.

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER settings disappear on logout so I created a User Preferences GPO that applied the regkey and it works for all users.

Comment: Thumbs up for the Group Policy!